# Зачем нужна @function в sass, когда есть @mixin?

Tags: css, css3, sass, scss

Зачем нужна `@function` в sass, когда есть `@mixin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница больше чисто идеологическая.

Mixin'ы - для определения кусков стилей, которые будут включатся в другие определения.

Функции - для вычисления и возврата какого-то одиночного значения, которое будет использоватся, скажем, в качестве значения свойства или как часть других вычислений.

Хотя на деле, в SASS/SCSS они взаимозаменяемы.